# There's and there're for places

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I've watched one video (I can't find it) about unusual using of everyday phrases 'there is' and 'there are'. The main point is using for defining absence (remoteness) of a person in some particular place

for example:

> phone conversation
>
> person 1 (New York) there **IS** a good weather
>
> person 2 (the United Kingdom) it's good that there **ARE** good weather *(about NY)*
>
> p 2 (UK) I heard that there **ARE** some outcry *(question about NY)*. Is it right?
>
> p 1 (NY) not really. There **IS** no any kind of outcry

conclusion: if some person is far away from some place the verb 'ARE' instead of 'IS' can be used in order to show his/her absence in some place

Question:

Is it right using or wrong or right only in common speaking?

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? Is this example something you made up yourself?

Comment: @Catija Read the explanation, please. I've explained the origin of this question (case). The conversation I've made up in order to convey the main point of confusion

Comment: Unless you can find the video, we may not be able to really address it. As per your own explanation, I'm writing an answer but it would seem that this video is outright incorrect. There is no implication of distance in the use of "is" or "are".

Comment: None of those sentences is grammatical.

Comment: Every one of the sentences in your example is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no proximity difference between whether someone uses "are" or "is". "Are" is used for **plural** and "is" is used for **singular** subjects.

Your sentences are simply wrong.

> New York has good weather
>   There is good weather in New York this week.
>   It's good that New York is having good weather this week.
>   Both New York and Philadelphia **are** having snow this weekend.

These sentences are correct regardless of whether the speaker is in New York or in India or the UK...